# How to control process affinity in .NET 2.0?

Tags: .net, process

How to control process affinity in .NET 2.0 ? I am newbie in .Net. 
please help !

Comment: Do you mean processOR affinity? Could you explain why you think you need to set this?

Comment: Usually you *don't* want to set processor affinity. Raymond Chen writes about what can happen if you do so without thinking about the consequences: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/21/399688.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at my post @[How to use hardware threads in C# dot net code running on multicore machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490711/how-to-use-hardware-threads-in-c-dot-net-code-running-on-multicore-machine/2491143#2491143)

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Process.ProcessorAffinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity(v=VS.90).aspx) property.

```
// this will cause the process to run only on CPU 1
Process.ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(1 << 0);
// this will cause the process to run only on CPU 1+2
Process.ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(1 << 0 | 1 << 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you do not. Sorry if that is not what you expect, but I do a LOT of server overview here and there and rarely - really rarely - see a need for that.

If you ahve to, look at the Process class - the ProcessAffinity property. But really make sure you have to in the first place.

Comment: I am not getting your answer.

Comment: In general, you DO NOT CONTROL AFFINITY. This is only usefull in VERY special cases, and I somehow dont think they apply to you. That simple. If it IS applicable, the Process class has a (documented) ProcessAffinity property that you can use. But again, most applications dont need that. Like "never".